# Just installed ngx-bootstrap and now getting Kestral error when running

Tags: c#, angular

Just wondering if I could have some help with something. I'm just working on my first Angular project and following a tutorial. I have just had to uninstall and re install part of Angular for downloading ngx-bootstrap as it wasn't working. That has now been successful but when I go to run the program I get the following error.

```
crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[0]
      Unable to start Kestrel.
      System.IO.IOException: Failed to bind to address https://127.0.0.1:5001: address already in use.
       ---> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.AddressInUseException: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.
       ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10048): Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.
         at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.UpdateStatusAfterSocketErrorAndThrowException(SocketError error, String callerName)
         at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoBind(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
         at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Bind(EndPoint localEP)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.SocketConnectionListener.<Bind>g__BindSocket|13_0(<>c__DisplayClass13_0& )
         --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.SocketConnectionListener.<Bind>g__BindSocket|13_0(<>c__DisplayClass13_0& )
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.SocketConnectionListener.Bind()
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.SocketTransportFactory.BindAsync(EndPoint endpoint, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Infrastructure.TransportManager.BindAsync(EndPoint endPoint, ConnectionDelegate connectionDelegate, EndpointConfig endpointConfig)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerImpl.<>c__DisplayClass29_0`1.<<StartAsync>g__OnBind|0>d.MoveNext()
      --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.BindEndpointAsync(ListenOptions endpoint, AddressBindContext context)
         --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.BindEndpointAsync(ListenOptions endpoint, AddressBindContext context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.LocalhostListenOptions.BindAsync(AddressBindContext context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.AddressesStrategy.BindAsync(AddressBindContext context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.BindAsync(IEnumerable`1 listenOptions, AddressBindContext context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerImpl.BindAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerImpl.StartAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Unhandled exception. System.IO.IOException: Failed to bind to address https://127.0.0.1:5001: address already in use.
 ---> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.AddressInUseException: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.
 ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10048): Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.UpdateStatusAfterSocketErrorAndThrowException(SocketError error, String callerName)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoBind(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Bind(EndPoint localEP)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.SocketConnectionListener.<Bind>g__BindSocket|13_0(<>c__DisplayClass13_0& )
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.SocketConnectionListener.<Bind>g__BindSocket|13_0(<>c__DisplayClass13_0& )
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.SocketConnectionListener.Bind()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.SocketTransportFactory.BindAsync(EndPoint endpoint, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Infrastructure.TransportManager.BindAsync(EndPoint endPoint, ConnectionDelegate connectionDelegate, EndpointConfig endpointConfig)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerImpl.<>c__DisplayClass29_0`1.<<StartAsync>g__OnBind|0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.BindEndpointAsync(ListenOptions endpoint, AddressBindContext context)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.BindEndpointAsync(ListenOptions endpoint, AddressBindContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostService.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost host, CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost host, CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.Run(IHost host)
   at API.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\Curtis.Holt\Desktop\DatingApp080221\api\Program.cs:line 16
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else is experiencing this - nice simple fix (reboot your pc)